# Renaming and rearranging multiple filenames without rename

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression, rename

I have almost 500 directories full of files with names like `e141107140847.pdf`, and I need to rename them to something user-friendly like `2014_11_SDUXS_0847.pdf`. I've been trying to use a for loop and sed, but I'm in over my head and can't figure out how to put everything together. I also don't have access to the `rename` command on this machine (FreeBSD).

The mapping is as follows:

- `e` — garbage character, to be removed
- `14` — translates to `SDUXS`. I have 36 different mappings to handle.
- `11` — month
- `07` — day, to be removed
- `14` — year, to be converted to 4 digits
- `0847` — location code, kept.

Comment: Do you have a snippet of working code?

Comment: Short answer is no- I can't get something that covers even half of what I need. I've tried a couple different approaches so far though:  

find . -type f -name 'e14*.pdf' -execdir mv {} SDUXS{} \;  

and

for file in e??????*; do echo mv $file $(echo $file | sed -e 's/^.....//'); done

Comment: Paste as far you haverá gone with a proper formating on the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So knocking this together for your specific example:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='e141107140847.pdf'
echo Given file name ${filename} -
case ${filename:1:2} in
  14)
    mapping="SDUXS"
    ;;
  *)
    mapping="XXXXX"
    ;;
esac
month="${filename:3:2}"
year="20${filename:7:2}"
location="${filename:9:4}"
echo New filename - ${year}_${month}_${mapping}_${location}.pdf
```

seems to give the result you seek.  Expand the `case..esac` statement for all of your mappings and wrap in a `for filename in *.pdf` and you can confirm the output; then just change the `echo` to:

```
mv "$filename" "${year}_${month}_${mapping}_${location}.pdf"
```

Comment: I adjusted this slightly to use $1 for the filename, and called it with find -execdir so I can customize the files passed in a little easier, but otherwise perfect.